# How can I change a slicer based on the selected parameter field in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, slicers

I have this chart:

[image: comparsion bar chart]

I want to present a comparison between years, or quarter-year, or month-year. In this example we have 2020 and 2021. What if I want to see quarter1-2020 vs quarter2-2023?

I have created this parameter:
[image]

And this metric to test it:

[image]

But I cannot use this in a slicer...Any ideas?